# Figuring out where the user clicked in a nested wx.Menu - wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm having trouble figuring out where the user clicked in a nested wx.Menu.

I have the following setup...
[image]

I would like a method to retrive the client's name, if he's checked in or if he's checkout and how long he ins't allowed in. The client's themselves doens't have any unique ID to them. Should I do that?

I haven't done that yet because clients will be appended and removed from those sub-menus at runtime, so I just don't know how to keep that organized and coese in the code.

Thank you!

***Edit: Here's my minimal example code:***

As I said before, I would hope to get the client's name trought the menu label itself to identify them. But if that's not possible, let's give them a unique ID. Mind that I will be removing and adding clients to those menus at runtime *(don't know how to do that yet. It seems pretty simple)*.

```
import wx

class ID:
    PUT_BACK = 1000
    WAIT_8 = 1001
    WAIT_16 = 1002
    WAIT_24 = 1003
    
    CHECK_IN = 1004
    CHECK_OUT = 1005

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        menu = wx.MenuBar()
        lobby = wx.Menu()
        check_in = wx.Menu()
        check_out = wx.Menu()

        wait_time = wx.Menu()
        wait_time.Append(ID.PUT_BACK, 'and put back in the queue')
        wait_time.Append(ID.WAIT_8, "and don't allow in for 8 hours")
        wait_time.Append(ID.WAIT_16, "and don't allow in for 16 hours")
        wait_time.Append(ID.WAIT_24, "and don't allow in for 24 hours")

        queue = ['George', 'Vanessa', 'Erick']
        for client in queue:
            _in = check_in.Append(ID.CHECK_IN, client)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnCheckIn, _in)

            _out = check_out.AppendSubMenu(wait_time, client)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnCheckOut, _out)

        lobby.AppendSubMenu(check_in, 'Check in...' )
        lobby.AppendSubMenu(check_out, 'Check out...')

        menu.Append(lobby, 'Lobby')
        self.SetMenuBar(menu)

    def OnCheckIn(self, event):
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        print('On Check in...')

    def OnCheckOut(self, event):
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        print(f'On Check out...')
        

app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: you need to assign ID's to the thing and check the id in the event listener... or bind only to a specific id `ID_NOW = wx.NewId()` iirc

Comment: You need to post example code, of how you are constructing the menu and how you are trying to to capture the click, or you run the risk of someone drawing you diagram as an answer. :)

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I added a minimal example code in my question. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making life difficult for yourself, taking the menu route. You may be better off choosing something like a `wx.Treectrl`.

With that caveat out of the way, menus rely on an `Id` reference but the menu itself and therefore sub-menus, don't have a user assigned Id, just the menu items within the menu.

That reference id must be unique.

This can make life tricky, if you need to carry some external reference forward through the menus, down into sub-menus, like a client reference, in this case.

You can create a `dict`, as complicated as required, and store the menu id's as you go. Then use that dictionary to retrieve information, based on those item id's, which are passed in the subsequent events.

It probably sounds more complicated than it is.

For example:

```
import wx

Actions = ["Check In", "Put Back", "Wait 8", "Wait 16", "Wait 24"]

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.SetTitle(title)
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        
        menu = wx.MenuBar()
        lobby = wx.Menu()
        check_in = wx.Menu()
        check_out = wx.Menu()

        # create dictionary of clients to store reference id's
        self.queue = {'George':[], 'Vanessa':[], 'Erick':[]}

        for client in self.queue:
            id = wx.NewIdRef()
            self.queue[client].append(id.Value)
            _in = check_in.Append(id, client, client)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnCheckIn, _in)

            PUT_BACK = wx.NewIdRef()
            WAIT_8 = wx.NewIdRef()
            WAIT_16 = wx.NewIdRef()
            WAIT_24 = wx.NewIdRef()
            self.queue[client].extend((PUT_BACK.Value,WAIT_8.Value,WAIT_16.Value,WAIT_24.Value))

            wait_time = wx.Menu()
            wait_time.Append(PUT_BACK, "and put back in the queue", client+" Back")
            wait_time.Append(WAIT_8, "and don't allow in for 8 hours", client+" +8")
            wait_time.Append(WAIT_16, "and don't allow in for 16 hours", client+" +16")
            wait_time.Append(WAIT_24, "and don't allow in for 24 hours", client+" +24")
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnCheckOut, id=PUT_BACK)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnCheckOut, id=WAIT_8)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnCheckOut, id=WAIT_16)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnCheckOut, id=WAIT_24)
            _out = check_out.AppendSubMenu(wait_time, client, client)

        lobby.AppendSubMenu(check_in, 'Check in...' )
        lobby.AppendSubMenu(check_out, 'Check out...')

        menu.Append(lobby, 'Lobby')
        self.SetMenuBar(menu)

    def OnCheckIn(self, event):
        id = event.GetId()
        # quiz the dictionary for the Client based on unique reference id's
        client = [c for c in self.queue if id in self.queue[c]]
        print('Check in...', client[0])

    def OnCheckOut(self, event):
        id = event.GetId()
        # quiz the dictionary for the Client based on unique reference id's
        client = [c for c in self.queue if id in self.queue[c]]
        # quiz the client entry for the action based on position (index)
        index = self.queue[client[0]].index(id)
        print(f'Check out..', client[0], "Action:",Actions[index])

app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(None, title="Check In/Out").Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code, ir really works, but I took a peek at this wx.TreeCtrl. Maybe it's better, it seems. I just couldn't find a function that gives me the text / label of the node the I click. All the functions I see, like GetItemText(), requires a ID to work. Well, how can I know that? Is there some kind of hit test to know where in the tree the user clicked to get its label and the label of it's predecessors? Or should I give up trying to make things work through label's and give everything unique IDs? Thanks!

Comment: Using wx.TreeCtrl now. Thank you! :D

Comment: @NeoFahrenheit Bind to `wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED` then `item = event.GetItem()` then `tree.GetItemText(item)`. `tree.GetItemParent(item)` takes you back up the tree.